# php mysql search all special characters

Tags: mysql

I cant figure out how to search for all special characters in mysql databse in single query.

For eg. search mysql and return the row whose column contains any of the special character like ",'#~;%*{ , etc. (means if some field have characters except 0-9, a-z, A-Z).

sample query type i want ---

```
SELECT * FROM mytable where column = 'PATTERN TO DETECT ALL SPECIAL CHARACTERS';
```

please also help with another query if i want to exclude some special chareacters like & ( ) . - from being searched.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your query would like this, check the regex

```
SELECT * 
FROM mytable 
WHERE column regexp '[^a-zA-Z0-9]'
```

And the second query would be similar

```
SELECT * 
FROM mytable 
WHERE column regexp '[^a-zA-Z0-9\&]'
```

\ + character to ignore

Comment: The `^` needs to be _after_ the `[`, and you don't want the `*` modifier.

Comment: Why do you need the `+` modifier? One special character is enough.

Comment: @felipep i also want to ignore hyphen (-). pls suggest changes in regex

Comment: SELECT * 
FROM mytable 
WHERE column regexp '[^a-zA-Z0-9\-]'

Comment: i was trying with regexp '[^a-zA-Z0-9 \-.&()]' which fails, putting \- and end like regexp '[^a-zA-Z0-9 .&()\-]' works. anyway thanks a lot for the help.

Answer (score 0):

Something like:

```
SELECT * FROM mytable where NOT(column REGEXP '^([:alnum:]|[:blank:])*$');
```

The '|' is an OR, the '[:alnum:]' matches anything alphanumeric, and `[:blank:]` matches whitespace (which you may or may not want), `^` matches the start and `$` matches the end. So it returns where `column` is NOT made up of alphanumerics or whitespace from start to finish. Alternatively you could list all the disallowed chars in a single `[]` clause and match them.

You can add other chars if some special chars are OK:

```
SELECT * FROM mytable where NOT(column REGEXP '^([:alnum:]|[:blank:]|[()&])*$');
```

See the documentation for more here: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/regexp.html

(I can't test the SQL from here, but I think I've got the syntax correct).

Answer (score 0):

This is the simplest way:

```
SELECT *
FROM mytable
WHERE column REGEXP '[^a-zA-Z0-9]'
```

Answer (score 0):

Try Using this query for searching special character records.

```
SELECT *
FROM tableName
WHERE fieldName REGEXP '[^a-zA-Z0-9@:. \'\-`,\&]'
```

We have removed symbols @ : dot(.) apostrophe (') hyphen (-) asterick(`) and comma(,) alphabets and numbers, so that we can see remaining special characters records.

Answer (score -1):

```
SELECT *
  FROM table
 WHERE column1 REGEXP '[$&+,:;=?@#|]';
```

For More Info: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/regexp.html

Comment: Those aren't all the special characters. He wants to match everything except alphanumerics.